Maui WebView error with selfsigned certificate
I'm using Maui webview to show my local angular app on http://192.168.1.X:4200
The Angular app in question uses .net core APIs hosted locally at https://192.168.1.Y/nameofapis
Starting my Maui app, I can show the Angular site, but every http request made to the service gives me the error:
net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
Usually when I use the Angular app directly from the browser (not from Maui), to solve this problem I just need to navigate to the service URL (https://192.168.1.Y/nameofapis) and authorize the self-signed certificate.
But I can't do this from the maui webview.
This is my code:
MainPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="test.MainPage"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:test.Controls">

    <ScrollView>     
        <controls:CustomWebView x:Name="MyWebView" Source="http://192.168.1.X:4200">
        </controls:CustomWebView>

    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>


MainPage.xaml.cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
    }   
}

CustomWebViewRenderer.cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace test.Platforms.Android
{
    public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public CustomWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
            global::Android.Webkit.WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }

    }
    public class CustomWebViewClient : global::Android.Webkit.WebViewClient
    {
        public CustomWebViewClient()
        {
        }

        public override void OnReceivedSslError(global::Android.Webkit.WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)
        {
            handler.Proceed();//this line make ssl error handle so the webview show the page even with certificate errors
        }
    }
}


CustomWebView.cs
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
        public CustomWebView()
        {
        }
}

How can I solve the problem?
